# Qt and OpenGL, using one context for multiple widgets

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I recently asked a question about how to get around sharing issues with vertex array objects and frame buffer objects across multiple contexts, I was then convinced that using multiple contexts just caused more headaches then solutions.

I am using Qt and currently my setup is that I have one invisible QGLWidget which I then use in the constructor of my visible QGLWidget's in order to share resources, this works great accept that I cannot share certain things across the contexts.

I wish to find a solution where I am able to use a single context to render all of my different widget's, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496728/multiple-qglwidgets-with-a-single-opengl-context-in-c) refers to using the QGLWidget constructor where you pass in the QGLContext you desire to be shared, however this does not seem to use one common context, but instead set the context to be used by one QGLWidget, when you try to use it on a second widget, a qWarning is called which informs you that the QGLContext must refer to the widget you are passing it to.

The goal of my application is to have 2 seperate GUI's which render different scenes, yet share the same context. Currently I have a 'World' editor which edits a scene and saves it to a file to be used in my game engine, and I also have a 'Material' editor which allows you to graphically edit a material similar to UDK's Material editor, there is a preview window which utilizes OpenGL.

Ideally I would like to keep my current design of having one unified game editor which is navigable by tabs, rather than having separate programs for each part of the editor.

The only thing that seemed like it was a decent solution was using the QGraphicsView and setting a QGLWidget as the viewport, however this does not seem to work at all. I can render basic primitives, however anything more and it falls apart.

Does anyone have experience dealing with this issue of multiple OpenGL Widgets, and if so could you explain the process you took to achieve your goal?

Comment: I'm constantly using QGraphicsView and it actually works well. What is the problem with it?

Comment: I simply create a QGraphicsView with a QGraphicsScene and then set the QGraphicsView viewport to my derived QGLWidget, if I render a basic primitive in the paint function of my QGLWidget it works, however when I try to render something using shaders it does not work, when I comment out the lines and replace the QGraphicsView widget with my QGLWidget, everything works fine again, it seems to be using it in tandem with the graphics view kills it

Comment: It actually stops my other QGLWidgets from working as well

Comment: I've made a question some time ago regarding the same ideas you are putting here. I've implemented a minimal example with a openGL+Qt which (hopefully) can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731626/qt-openglscene-working-example/12550627#12550627

Comment: I tried to access your site but it wouldn't let me, I requested access now *Nevermind it let me in*

Comment: Yeah sorry, it won't let me access the 'code-reservoir/opengl/'

Comment: -.-' I'm a little noob in google sites, try now.

Comment: That works great now, I already tried something similar but I must have missed something.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19316/discussion-between-user1294021-and-j-c-leitao)

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand why you are having so much trouble, I'm building a CAD-like app so share a few contexts, like this:

- I use an application-wide hidden `QGLWidget` as a member of my main window class, this is the context shaders are loaded in.
- For each document window, the window class has a hidden `QGLWidget` member, this is the context geometry is loaded in.  The shader context is used as the 'shared' widget for it, allowing documents access to the application wide shaders.
- Each of the 5 viewports in each document window is a visible `QGLWidget`, this is where the actual rendering takes place.  The document window geometry `QGLWidget` is used as the 'shared' widget, so the viewports have access to the document-wide geometry data and the application-wide shaders.

The shared widget parameter allows you to create an 'inheritance' tree of contexts, every context has access to it's own and all it's ancestors data (but not it's childrens or siblings).